# MongoDB - Only binding to either IPv4 or IPv6, not both?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

So my initial problem was when I had specified within mongod.conf to listen on both an IPv4 and IPv6 address- it spit out an error "getaddrinfo failed: Address family for hostname not supported". So after searching around, apparently you should set "ipv6: true" within the net property for it to function properly. However, now MongoDB only listens on the IPv6 address.

Here's a current snippet of my config file:

```
 net:
      ipv6: true
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1,ipv4Address,ipv6Address
```

There seems to be no error in the log file...

This is the most recent version of MongoDB.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should only need your server ip

```
net:
  ipv6: true
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,XX.XX.XX.XX
```

then use your firewall to allow both ipv4 and ipv6

```
sudo ufw allow PORT#/tcp
```